# Finding intensity λ

Tags: probability

Bubbles are distributed in sheets of glass as a Poisson process at an intensity of 1.2 bubbles per square meter. Let X be the number of sheets of glass in a shipment of n sheets which have no bubbles. Each sheet is 0.8 m^2.

The glass manufacturer wants to have at least 50% of the sheets of glass wit no bubbles. How can I find the intensity λ? I have already found the probability function of X.

Comment: "I have already found the probability function of $X$." - please elaborate.

Comment: function is P(X=x) = (n choose x)*(e^-0.96)^x * (1-e^-0.96)^(n-x) since 0.8 times 1.2 is 0.96

Comment: Doesn't that seem like relevant information to add to the question?